# Use Invoke-Item calling .exe with variable folder path and passing /qn argument

Tags: powershell

I struggling to find whats wrong with my code.
Im trying to uninstall an app on several Windows 10 clients, where the path to the .exe is different on any machine. I use `Get-ChildItem` to get that specific folder. Now im trying to execute that path with the .exe at the end and add a `/qn` trigger to silently deinstall.
However, i always get back errors regarding the `Invoke-Item` function.

Here is my script:

First im trying to find the variable foldername inside the app folder:

```
$path_to_exe = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Program Files\ApplicationName" -Include "installer.exe" -Recurse | 
Where-Object { $_.FullName -match '\{(.*)\}' }
```

Which gives me the path as a `Get-ChildItem` response.

Now i convert the path given from `Get-ChildItem` to a "Normal" Path

```
$path_to_exe = Convert-Path $Path_to_exe.PSPath
```

Now i try to call the path i found with the `/qn` trigger to silently deinstall.

```
"`"$path_to_exe`"" + " /qn" | Invoke-Item
```

Im 100% sure that my approach is a beginner tier one.
If anyone has a better idea, please educate me.

Thanks :)

EDIT:

The manufacturer states i should use the following:

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{1D9F5D88-12AA-427F-8A33-DED71D60E4D9} - MsiExec.exe /X{1D9F5D88-12AA-427F-8A33-DED71D60E4D9}
```

Does anybody have an idea how i can extract that guid from the `Get-ChildItem` registry query?

Comment: Good first post - only missing one thing - the error you're encountering when calling `Invoke-Item`. That said, I'd probably try something like `& "$path_to_exe" "/qn"` ?

Comment: Are you sure the exe accepts switch `\qn` ? Normally this is used for [.msi files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/msiexec#parameters-1)

Comment: @WaitingForGuacamole Thanks for the comment. The error i get was that `Invoke-Item` didn't handle the `/qn` part properly. I now used the `&` operator how you described and the script ran without errors. However i have no idea what it now did and didn't to.  Im trying to find a better solution...

Comment: OK, so use `& MsiExec.exe /X{1D9F5D88-12AA-427F-8A33-DED71D60E4D9} \qn`

Comment: @Theo Issue is, the GUID is different for every installation if i understand correctly.

Comment: Here's the problem if you want log output - usually an installer with a "quiet/noprompt" switch is not going to log to a console. You'd have to look to see if there were any log files created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out! As i knew, i had the wrong approach. I was making it way to complicated trying to parse the `EXE` file to a seperate powershell instance and adding arguments.
I rewrote my whole code using the `msiexec` function.

So first i needed to find out the GUID of the app using the `Get-ChildItem` function.

```
$Path_to_GUID = Get-ChildItem -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall, HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall  |
    Get-ItemProperty |
        Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -match "Application Name" } |
            Select-Object -Property DisplayName, UninstallString
```

Now i had the desired path of that `Get-ChildItem` object, with the `.UninstallString` property.
Since i only want the GUID itself, i used the `Split-Path` function to separate the path by the folder name/GUID which in the beginning somewhat looked like this:

```
HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx}\installer.exe
```

So using the `Split-Path` function i first only cut the `-Parent` part.

```
$Path_to_GUID = Split-Path -Path $Path_to_GUID.UninstallString -Parent
```

Which gave me the path like this, without the installer.exe at the end:

```
HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx}
```

So now i only want the part of the path with the curly braces using the `-Leaf` argument:

```
$Path_to_GUID = Split-Path $Path_to_GUID -Leaf
```

Which gave me the desired string:

```
{xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx}
```

Now i just had to uninstall using `msiexec` and adding the silent parameter:

```
msiexec /x $Path_to_GUID /qn
```

Here's the full code (Powershell):

```
$Path_to_GUID = Get-ChildItem -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall, HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall  |
        Get-ItemProperty |
            Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -match "Application Name" } |
                Select-Object -Property DisplayName, UninstallString

$Path_to_GUID = Split-Path -Path $Path_to_GUID.UninstallString -Parent
$Path_to_GUID = Split-Path $Path_to_GUID -Leaf

msiexec /x $Path_to_GUID /qn
```

Answer (score 1):

```
get-package "*applicationname*" | uninstall-package
```

Comment: That probably works. Since i was dealing with a AntiVirus software, i havent tested if that works.